# Rubinus 2.0 for ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby

Is Rubinus 2.0 compatible with Ruby 2.0? I tried the latest Rubinus 2.0, but it seems to only support Ruby 1.9.3. I already have the app running on ruby 2.0, so going back to 1.9.3 is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; Rubinius is currently fully compatible with Ruby 1.8.7 and is targeting 1.9.3 compatibility, according to [their readme](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius#readme) and [their web site](http://rubini.us/doc/en/what-is-rubinius/).

Answer (score 4):

It is now compatible with Ruby 2.1

http://rubini.us/2013/10/04/rubinius-2-0-released/